# Why shear stress is assumed constant in the inner layer?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, boundary-conditions, navier-stokes

In the derivation of the log-law and the viscous sub-layer velocity profiles, it is customary to assume that the shear stress is constant and equal to the wall shear stress. Is there any physical or mathematical reasoning for that?

Comment: Yes.  The inner layer is very thin compared to the radius of the tube, so the variation of the shear stress over the wall layer is negligible.  For flow in a tube, $\tau=\tau_w\frac{r}{R}$, and r is very nearly equal to R over the entire wall layer.

Comment: By Taylor-expanding the velocity field near a wall you can show that the flow close to the wall is a simple shear flow (with higher order corrections that are negligible at small distances from the wall). In simple shear flow, the cross-stream velocity gradient and hence the shear stress is indeed constant.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think you are referring to the no-slip assumption, where fluid flowing through a tube is assumed to be stationary at the outside edges. There is a very simple and intuitive reason that we make that assumption: It's true.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cUTkqZeiMow

The friction force between fluid particles is low, and the friction force between a layer of fluid particles and the wall of a pipe (especially under pressure) is high, so the outside layer of water doesn't go anywhere. The fact that it is *amazingly* convenient is a side bonus. Please let me know if I'm misunderstanding your question.